# NFA from regular expression

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-expressions, formal-grammar

I'm trying to make an NFA from the following regular expression.

[image]

I'm not sure about the edges between nodes $q2$ and $q4$, maybe someone can point out where everything went wrong.

Comment: Is the empty word ($\lambda$) allowed as input??

Comment: yes. $q6$ could maybe be the final state and $a$ might be another edge $q5 \to q6$ and cut out $q7$ completely.  I'm wondering if that would be better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should merge $q_2$ and $q_4$ and remove the $\lambda$-transitions between them, but keep the transition labelled by $c$.
You should also replace $q_6 \xrightarrow{a} q_7$ by $q_5 \xrightarrow{a} q_7$.
The states $q_6$ and $q_7$ should then be both final.

Comment: I'm not sure why to merge $q2$ and $q4$. Is it just wrong or is it just extraneous?

Comment: It is not wrong, but it is really unnecessary. Indeed, you have two transitions $q_2 \xrightarrow{\lambda} q_4$ and $q_4 \xrightarrow{\lambda} q_4$ so you can freely pass from $q_2$ to $q_4$ and back.